# Allocating memory for class in C++

Tags: c++, class, memory, vector

This is my class:

```
using namespace std;

Class Book {
    public:
        Book();
        Book(vector<string>*, string, int);
        Book(const Book&);
        ~Book();
        Book& operator=(const Book&);
        void update(vector<string>*);
        void update(string); 
        void update(int); 
        int getYear() const{
            return year;
        };
        string getTitle() const{
            return title;
        };
        bool operator==(const Book&);
        bool operator!=(const Book&);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Book&);
        void getAuthors();
    private:
        vector<string>* authors;
        string title;
        int year;
};

#endif  /* BOOK_H */
```

Here is the source for it:

```
#include "Book.h"
using namespace std;

Book::Book():year(0), title(NULL), authors(NULL){}
Book::Book(vector<string>* bookauthors,string booktitle, int bookyear ){
    authors = bookauthors;
    title = booktitle;
    year = bookyear;
}

Book::Book(const Book& aBook){
    authors = aBook.authors;
    title = aBook.title;
    year = aBook.year;
}

Book::~Book(){
    delete authors;
    delete &title;
    delete &year;
}

bool Book::operator==(const Book &aBook){
    if(getYear() == aBook.getYear() && getTitle() == aBook.getTitle())
        return true;
    else return false;
}

bool Book::operator != (const Book &aBook){
    if(getYear() != aBook.getYear() && getTitle() != aBook.getTitle())
        return true;
    else return false;
}

Book& Book::operator =(const Book& rhs){
    if(this != &rhs){
        authors = rhs.authors;
        title = rhs.title;
        year = rhs.year;
    }
    return *this;
}

void Book::update(int newyear){
    year = newyear;
}

void Book::update(string newtitle){
    title = newtitle;    
}

void Book::update(vector<string>* newauthors){
    authors = newauthors;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Book& b){
    os<<b.getTitle()<<", "<<b.getYear();
    return os;
}
```

Here is the main file where it runs:

```
    #include "Book.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
//This is the test funcion posted on the class website
using namespace std;

int main(){

  //testing constructor
  vector<string> authors;
  authors.push_back("Ritchie");
  authors.push_back("Kernighan");
  Book a(&authors, "C", 1990);
  authors.push_back("Whatever");
  cout << "Book a is: " << a << endl;
  cout << "Expected: (C, 1990, Ritchie & Kernighan)" << endl;

  //testing copy constructor
  Book b(a);
  a.update(&authors);
  cout << "Book b is: " << b << endl;
  cout << "Expected: (C, 1990, Ritchie & Kernighan)" << endl;

  //testing constructor
  vector<string> authors2;
  authors2.push_back("Crockford");
  Book c(&authors2, "JavaScript", 2008);
  cout << "Book c is: " << c << endl;
  cout << "Expected: (JavaScipt, 2008, Crockford)" << endl;

  //testing assignment operator
  authors2.push_back("whatever");
  a=c;
  cout << "Book a is changed to: " << a << endl;
  cout << "Expected: (JavaScipt, 2008, Crockford)" << endl;

  for(int i=0; i < 200000000; i++)
    b=c;
  cout << "Book b is changed to: " << b << endl;
  cout << "Expected: (JavaScipt, 2008, Crockford)" << endl;
}
```

I keep getting this when I run it:

> bookclass(58316) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff522d78b0: pointer being freed was not   allocated*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I'm new to C++ so I'm not sure how to allocate the memory. I tried using `malloc` and it didn't work.

Comment: Why is it a pointer to a vector? What exactly is it going to end up like? Those `delete`s and that pointer are very likely unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

The members are located inside the object, i.e., the memory for them is allocated with the `Book` object and neither can nor need to `delete` the memory explicitly. Basically, you need to match your explicit allocations using `new` with calls to `delete` but you never need to release something which isn't allocated somewhere explicitly.

That is, you get the error when you try to `delete title` or `delete year`. It may also happen when trying to `delete authors` depending on where `authors` is coming from. In general, you don't want to `delete` objects you haven't allocated. Your `Book` class possibly unreasonably takes ownership of the `authors` vector.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a good time to learn to use Valgrind, which will give you much richer debugging facilities for this kind of error.

In your destructor, you are destroying title and year via a pointer. You do not actually need to do this, as they are allocated statically (i.e. you didn't create them using new), so it's complaining that you are trying to delete something you did not create dynamically.

In addition, you are deleting your `std::vector`, which can refer to the same `std::vector` contained within another class. Since it's possible you have two classes containing the same reference, you need to find a smarter way to delete this so you don't invoke a double free.

Comment: Or smarter solution: Just use a normal vector instead of a pointer to one.

Comment: @BrendanLong - oh yes, of course. For some reason, my brain still likes to assume they had a reason to use a pointer to a vector, even if there isn't a good reason for it.