# Allocating memory of vector whose type is own Class C++

Tags: c++, memory, vector, alloc

I've so far few posts about allocating memory for vectors

( [Allocating memory for class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905102/allocating-memory-for-class-in-c)
[Allocating memory for class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905102/allocating-memory-for-class-in-c), for example)
but I didn't manage to find the solution for the problem I'm facing right now.

Let's go.. According to S.Prata,

```
tab.push_back();
```

allocates the memory for the new object we put into the vector called "tab"
If so on, we do not have to state the length of the vector within the declaration, right?

```
vecotr<Type> tab;
```

So,, Knowing these facts, I want to share sth with you.

instrumenty.h

```
#pragma once
#include "portfel.h"
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Spolka;

class Akcja
{
    std::shared_ptr<Spolka> firma;
    double cena_zakupu;
    double cena_aktualna;
public:
    Akcja();
    ~Akcja();
};

class Obligacja
{
    int a;
public:
    Obligacja();
    ~Obligacja();
};

class Kontrakt
{
    int a;
public:
    Kontrakt();
    ~Kontrakt();
};
```

Now goes "portfel.h"

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "instrumenty.h"

class Akcja;
class Obligacja;
class Kontrakt;

class Portfel
{
    friend class Inwestor;
    int a;
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Akcja> > akcje;
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Obligacja> > obligacje;
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Kontrakt> > kontrakty;
public:
    Portfel();
    ~Portfel();
    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& zapisz, Portfel& p1);
};
```

portfel.cpp ( the reason of the problem)

```
Portfel::Portfel()
{
    a=0;
    akcje.push_back(NULL);     //   <------- THIS THING
    //akcje.reserve(class Akcja);  //  <-- How to properly define this according to
                                       portfel.h?
}
```

The output is some kind of bush

[image]

How to properly allocate memory for such types of vector that consist of smart pointers to own defined class as a Type?

```
==3238== Invalid read of size 2
==3238==    at 0x409336: operator<<(std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Inwestor*) (zapis.cpp:13)
==3238==    by 0x4066B5: Inwestor::nowy_profil() (inwestor.cpp:116)
==3238==    by 0x404B00: menu1() (funkcje.cpp:97)
==3238==    by 0x40208E: main (main.cpp:27)
==3238==  Address 0x5a07140 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==3238==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3238==    by 0x408B13: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:94)
==3238==    by 0x40892A: std::_Vector_base<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> > > >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/rideofyourlife/Pulpit/DM/all)
==3238==    by 0x4084C3: void std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> > > >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> > >(std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> >&&) (vector.tcc:405)
==3238==    by 0x408234: void std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> > > >::emplace_back<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> > >(std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> >&&) (vector.tcc:102)
==3238==    by 0x407E5D: std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> > > >::push_back(std::unique_ptr<Akcja, std::default_delete<Akcja> >&&) (stl_vector.h:900)
==3238==    by 0x407AE2: Portfel::Portfel() (portfel.cpp:6)
==3238==    by 0x405D07: Inwestor::Inwestor() (inwestor.cpp:13)
==3238==    by 0x402126: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (main.cpp:14)
==3238==    by 0x402161: _GLOBAL__sub_I_q (main.cpp:31)
==3238==    by 0x40985C: __libc_csu_init (in /home/rideofyourlife/Pulpit/DM/all)
==3238==    by 0x536D6FF: (below main) (libc-start.c:185)
```

Comment: How do you declare your `Portfel` object? What do you do in the `Inwestor` constructor?

Comment: In Inwestor::Inwestor I do

     Portfel p1;

Comment: The error you pasted happens when `Inwestor::nowy_profil()` calls `operator<<`. Please show that method.

Comment: Where is the "vector whose type is its own class"?

Answer (score 0):

To add a pointer to a new `Akcja` to the vector, you would say

```
akcje.push_back(new Akcja);
```

You usually don't need to manage `vector` memory at all - that's what the class is for.

In particular, `reserve` is used to make sure there is room for all elements when you know beforehand how much you're going to need so you can save the time needed to reallocate and copy the vector to a new place as it grows, or to avoid memory fragmentation (which is very rare to need to worry about).
It's not used for adding elements.